# Freestyle is confusing me - Cycles Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle

I have been trying for the past 3 days to try and get freestyle to work in Blender cycles, but I can only find tutorials for Blender  Internal.

I *don't* like working in Internal, but I can't figure out how to get the freestyle to work in Cycles!

I am not a seasoned blender-ist, so please explain with pictures

Answer (score 1):

[image]

So the thing is Cycyles viewport rendering doesnot support freestyle yet so you will have to render the scene to see the freestyle in action!

Comment: click the tick mark so people can know this question has been answered!